# Laravel 5.2 get value field only in json response

Tags: php, json, laravel

Here is my code

```
$temp  = $this->whereBetween('id', [$sid,$eid])
                        ->select('id','temperature')
                        ->get();
```

will return

```
[{"id":1,"temperature":34.5},{"id":2,"temperature":32.56},
```

how do i get only result like this, remove the key and pass the value only.

```
[{1,34.5},{2,32.56}]
```

I have using **lists** but it only return partial or all field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to rebuild the array. I've tested this code and it works:

```
$array = [];
foreach($temp as $k => $v) {
    $array[] = [$v['id'], $v['temperature']];
}
```

After that just serialize this array or use as is.

Comment: still the result is with key and values.

Comment: @ShafiqMustapa I've updated my answer with tested solution.

Comment: tested, and the end result is this
```[[1,34.5],[2,32.56]]```
I want to be like ```[{1,34.5},{2,32.56}]``` @Alexey Mazenin

Answer (score 0):

The function that you search, is [array_values](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php).
Iterate over your array, use that function, and save it back to an array.

For example:

```
$newArray = array();
foreach ($temp as $row) {
    $newArray[] = array_values($row);
}
```